# How to connect remote myqli sever with node js

Tags: node.js

hey guys I want to connect my MySQL database that is on hostinger to my nodejs webapp that is hosted in digital ocean remotely

Comment: What package are you using to connect? usually it's the same as on local, just replace "localhost" with the remote IP

Comment: I am using mysql module to conect database but it's work perfectly on localhost but when I enter IP it's send a error timeout

Comment: first mane sure that the server is installed correctly on your machine, on the right port (3306) and that it up and runing

Comment: Bro I am using mysql node js module it's work perfectly on localhost but when I try to connect it from my droplet it's return con time out did you know how to connect remote MySQL sever with node js any pice of code help me a lot

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.